# Will GWT2.2.1 support java7?

Tags: java, gwt, java-7, smartgwt, gwt2

I am using java 6 with GWT2.2.1, but the current requirement is to upgrade java from java 6 to Java 7. Is it possible to upgrade?

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 support was [added in GWT 2.6.0](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_6_0_RC1). On the server side, you can use whatever Java version you like. However on the client side, you won't be able to use Java 7 features with GWT <2.6.0. You *can* use a Java 7 (or even 8) JDK to compile your project, just force it to use Java 6 (and of course, don't use features from Java >6 in your client side code), for example, using `-sourceLevel 6`.

Comment: Many Thanks @Igor Klimer, just would like to know: <br/> 1. can we upgrade the GWT version from 2.2.1 to 2.6.0 (or current version of GWT)?<br/> 2. What all changes i need to do to upgrade the GWT? <br/> Please dont mistake me, if i asked very silly question in this group as i need to migrate the code to higher version so i find this is the best place to put my question.

Comment: It's impossible for me to tell you can you upgrade effortlessly *your* project without having access to the source code. There were probably breaking changes between 2.2.1 and 2.6.0 and judging by the tags you're also using SmartGWT - that could also affect the upgrade. Just do it (tm) and see if the project compiles, the layout is the same, tests pass, etc.